# Linq Distinct on list

Tags: linq, distinct

I have a list like this:

List people

```
age   name
1     bob
1     sam
7     fred
7     tom
8     sally
```

I need to do a linq query on people and get an int of the number distinct ages (3)

```
int distinctAges = people.SomeLinq();
```

how?
how?

Comment: This is an extremely simple question, so it sounds like homework to us.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check out `GroupBy` and `Count`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select out the age, then use Distinct and Count.

```
 var ages = people.Select( p => p.Age ).Distinct().Count()
```

Or you could use GroupBy and Count

```
 var ages = people.GroupBy( p => p.Age ).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Download [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and give these simple linq / lambda queries yourself. Its very easy to compare the SQL and equivalent Linq / lambda result set.

You would start with

```
select  Age, Name
from    People
group   by Age, Name
```

Then open another tab

```
var ages = (from    p in Peoples
group p by p.Age into g
select g);
ages.Dump();
```

Then open another tab

```
var ages = Peoples.GroupBy(p => p.Age);
ages.Dump();
```